# Changing Javascript object properties through a pointer to the original object?

Tags: javascript, pointers, object

I'm running into an error that I'm not sure how to resolve.  I have the function update() below that takes in an object and then performs logic on it.

```
     var requestAnimFrame = ( function() {
                 return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    function(callback) {
                       window.setTimeout(callback, 10);  
                    };
                })();

     function doAnimation(ballObject) {
        requestAnimFrame(doAnimation);
        update(ballObject);
        console.log( getProperty("ball","top") );
        console.log( getProperty("ball","left") );
     }

 function Ball(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.xVel = .17;
    this.yVel = .13;
    this.ts;
 }

     function update(ball){

        // do timestamp calculations
        var newBall = ball;
        var ts = Date.now();             
        newBall.ts = newBall.ts || ts;
        var time_elapsed = ts - newBall.ts;
        newBall.ts = ts;            

        // get values from ball
        var ball_y = parseFloat( getProperty(newBall.id,"top").replace ("px", "") ) || 0;
        var ball_x = parseFloat( getProperty(newBall.id,"left").replace("px", "") ) || 0;

        // do other things, such as set new location for the ball's top and
        // left position and etc.
     }

  // Code that starts the entire process
         (function() {
            ball = new Ball("ball");
            doAnimation(ball);
         })();
```

As you can see from this exert of my function above, I am trying to assign the property "ts" on the "newBall" object to the value held by the local variable named "ts".  However, when I go to do that assignment, the entire value of the "newBall" object becomes the value of the local variable "ts" instead of just the "newBall" object's "ts" property.  I'm assuming this is reflective of an error in my syntax, but I really don't have any clue?  Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

I know that from c++ pointers, you have to de-reference the pointer before you can access the properties of the pointer object.  Do I somehow have to do the same thing here?

EDIT: I have included my class declaration before my update() function, as well as the two functions that manage the repeated call to update.

Comment: Your syntax seems correct. Why do you have the second assignment to `newBall.ts`?

Comment: @Max, your code looks fine. What are you passing in as the parameter "ball" when you call the function? And no, in JavaScript, there's no referencing or de-referencing like in C++. It's a very different language.

Comment: @RenatoZannon Originally I didn't understand that objects were passed by reference, so I created the newBall object, changed its properties, and then returned that at the function's conclusion.  I later learned this was unnecesary but didn't yet go back and take out the references to newBall.

Comment: @JoshBeam I have a Ball class, an object of which I passed into the update function.  The Ball class (and its associated objects) has a property of "id" and "ts".

Comment: It's not actually pass-by-reference. It's pass-by-value, but the value is a pointer (in C/C++ terms), and the property access is equivalent to C/C++ `->`. The difference comes from the fact that, if you assign `ball` to other value, the original `ball` on the call site isn't changed.

Comment: If I'm understanding your post, then I have a possible issue with my original object not being updated when I change the copy of it that was passed into the function.  I'm going to edit my comment to include the code from my class declaration, so a problem can maybe be identified with how I did that.

Comment: I still can't see any (syntactic) issue in your code. Maybe you can put a reproduction of the problem in http://jsbin.com ? On a side note, the last line on the `Ball` constructor is unnecessary

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kopok/3/edit?css,js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on your `doAnimation` function:

```
function doAnimation(ballObject) {
  requestAnimFrame(doAnimation);
  update(ballObject);
  /* Logging here */
}
```

When `requestAnimationFrame` calls your function again, it won't have the `ballObject` argument passed to it. In fact, it will be passed a high-resolution timestamp, which is what you're getting manually (with less precision) on the `update` function. For more information on how `requestAnimationFrame` works, check out [the documentation at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame).

Going back to the `ballObject` argument, you need to use some other way to maintain reference to it. Normally in javascript this is achieved through closures:

```
function doAnimation(ballObject) {
  requestAnimFrame(function() {
    doAnimation(ballObject);
  });

  update(ballObject);
  /* Logging here */
}
```

A working version of your example: http://jsbin.com/nebucedo/2/edit?js,output

Comment: I really appreciate your help in figuring this out :)  Now that you've pointed this out, it makes a lot of sense as to why it didn't work correctly in the beginning.  Thanks!